# fb:comments blows up with bunch of js errors

Tags: facebook, comments

I am trying to use FB Comments plugin and while plugin seems to load and work, my site blows up with bunch of Facebook js errors:

- Error: 'parseInt' is undefined
- Error: 'Object' is undefined
- Error: 'FB_RequireFeatures' is undefined
- Error: 'Date' is undefined
- Error: Unable to get value of the property 'setResourceMap': object is null or undefined
- Error: Unable to get value of the property 'configurePage': object is null or undefined

My web page schema is as following:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" "//static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
FB.init("{appKey}","http://commoninterview.com/modules/fb/xd_receiver.htm");
</script>

HTML...

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<fb:comments href="{pageURL}" num_posts="10" width="760"></fb:comments>

HTML...

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init("{appKey}","http://commoninterview.com/modules/fb/xd_receiver.htm");
</script>
```

Live Example: http://commoninterview.com/interview_puzzles/filling-matrix-interview-puzzle-1/

**Any help or pointers are appreciated !**

Comment: If you remove the comment plugin does the errors go away? When I visit that page I dont get the errors you describe, but I get a ton of other errors..mismatching http/https..cross domain issues, and other random stuff

Comment: Thanks for looking. If I remove comment plugin js errors goes away.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a compatibility issue.

See this snippet taken from this page: "If you upgrade to the new JavaScript SDK, please ensure you remove all references to the old JavaScript library, as they are incompatible and will cause your implementation to stop working. You can find references to the old JavaScript library by searching for the string "FeatureLoader.js.php"."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/

It looks like you are mixing old deprecated FB JS code

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. However I start getting mixed content warnings, but looks like even facebook plugin page has same problem:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/